# Estimation accuracy of precision matrix

Tags: estimation, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

I have a couple of questions related to estimation of high-dimensional precision matrix (inverse of the covariance matrix) in the case where p is close to 100 and n < p. As a measure of estimation accuracy I am calculating a 'relative squarred error' defined in the following manner: 
$$
RSE(\Sigma^{-1},\hat{\Sigma^{-1}}) = \frac{||{\Sigma^{-1}-\hat{\Sigma^{-1}}}||}{||\Sigma^{-1}||}
$$

where, $||A|| = \sum_{i,j}a_{ij}^2 $ is the Frobenius norm of $A$. Now, my questions are,

a) Is there any known result for lower bound of Frobenius norm of a precision matrix? or for that matter, any general matrix?

b) What are the common ways of showing the estimation accuracy of a method. I think we can of course calculate various norms such as the spectral norm etc, but, is there a graphical way of doing this?

I appreciate any kind of help and apologies in advance if this is not the right place or way to ask such questions.

Comment: I think we'll need some more information about what you're really interested in to be helpful. Here are some initial comments: (**1**) You've written the *squared* Frobenius norm on the RHS of your definition of $\|A\|$. (**2**) Consider the diagonal matrices. That should tell you everything you need to know about possible values that $\mathrm{RSE}$ can take on (knowing nothing further about the structure of your problem). (**3**) Answering your question (b) will require knowing more about your interests and application.

Comment: Thanks @cardinal. Yes, it's the squarred Frobenius norm. About the lower bound, I am trying to see how good is the RSE I am getting for my method, having a lower bound should help with that. I think considering diagonal matrices is a way of doing that. For part b), I am applying this method of estimation for a data-set where I know the population precision matrix should have a block diagonal structure, then the estimated precision matrix should have a similar structure. How do I demonstrate that using graphical outputs? Also, does having a low RSE imply preservation of the matrix-structure?

Comment: The direction I was trying to point you in regarding diagonal matrices was that (**1**) the *lower bound* is, of course, zero and that (**2**) the upper bound is infinity. The first is seen simply by taking $\Sigma^{-1} = {\hat\Sigma}^{-1}$ and for the second, just fix $\Sigma$ at any arbitrary positive semidefinite matrix and let $\hat\Sigma^{-1}$ be a diagonal matrix with entries that grow without bound.